# Как сделать слайдер из вкладок?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день. Есть блок с 7 вкладками. Вкладка - подобие кнопки, нажимая на нее появляется определенный блок с инфой. Как мне сделать слайдер вкладок? Все 7 не умещаются на экране, только 5 штук. Я попробовал слайдер slick и вкладки tabs от jquery-ui. Одно из двух работает точно. Типа вот этого [слайдера](http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs/). Что подскажете?

Comment: в чем, собственно, проблема? уместить 7 вкладок на экран? тогда это в раздел "впихнуть невпихуемое", вероятно - сокращайте содержимое вкладок, например

Comment: @lexxl проблема сделать слайдер из 7 вкладок, не знаю как! А то что они не впихиваются, то это решиться при помощи слайдера ни как иначе. Есть что дельное подсказать?

Comment: в slick есть свойство asNavFor, сделайте слайдер вкладок, сам слайдер и свяжите их.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko хех) нашел http://codepen.io/jeffpannone/pen/GpKOed  спасибо)